# How to connect Apache Ignite with NestJS?

Tags: node.js, ignite, memorycache, apacheignite

I'm trying to connect Apache Ignite with Nest JS. I'm getting error regarding the library I used: 'apache-ignite-client'.

```
Error: TypeError: apache_ignite_client_1.default is not a constructor.
```

## Code

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import IgniteClient from 'apache-ignite-client';
import SqlFieldsQuery from 'apache-ignite-client';

@Injectable()
export class AlarmsService {

    private igniteClient: IgniteClient;
    constructor(
    ) {
        this.igniteClient = new IgniteClient();
    }
    
    async connect() {
        await this.igniteClient.connect('localhost:10800');
    }

    async getData() {
        await this.connect();
        const query = new SqlFieldsQuery.query("SELECT * FROM alarms");
        const result = await this.igniteClient.query(query);
        return result.getAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `apache-ignite-client` library doesn't support ES modules import you should use CommonJS import instead, as shown below:

```
const IgniteClient = require('apache-ignite-client');
```

Also, I would like to notice that there are several additional issues in your code:

1. `IgniteClientConfiguration` object should be used instead of `String` for `igniteClient.connect(cfg)` method execution.
2. `SqlFieldsQuery` doesn't have a `query` method, the SQL query string should be passed in `SqlFieldsQuery`'s constructor instead.
3. The `cache.query()` method should be used instead of `igniteClient.query()` to execute the query.

More details regarding that can be found in the documentation [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/thin-clients/nodejs-thin-client#executing-sql-statements).

Also, here is an example that is based on your code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

const IgniteClient = require('apache-ignite-client');
const SqlFieldsQuery = IgniteClient.SqlFieldsQuery;
const IgniteClientConfiguration = IgniteClient.IgniteClientConfiguration;

@Injectable() 
export class AlarmsService {
    private igniteClient: any;

    constructor() {
        this.igniteClient = new IgniteClient();
    }

    async connect() {
        const igniteClientConfiguration = new IgniteClientConfiguration('127.0.0.1:10800');
        await this.igniteClient.connect(igniteClientConfiguration);
    }

    async getData() {
        await this.connect();
        const cache = await this.igniteClient.getOrCreateCache('alarms');
        const query = new SqlFieldsQuery('SELECT * FROM alarms');
        const result = await cache.query(query);
        return result.getAll();
    }
}
```